# Accessing Stored Core Data Entities from Different Classes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

I am quite new to Core Data, and I'm trying to implement it into my relatively simple OS X application. My application takes some file URLs provided by the user, gets some more information about the files (like creation date, for example), and then stores the URLs for use later.

I am wanting to have those file URLs, and related data, stored in a 'central' location so I can access, modify, and change the order of them (order is really important) from any of the classes in my application (correct me if I'm wrong, but I think Core Data is ideal for this).

I have my Core Data Model setup in Xcode (it only has one Entity which has a couple of Attributes), I've create an NSManagedObject Subclass to match the Entity in the Model, and I'm using Bindings to tie the data to a TableView. However, like I said, I need to be able get at this data from any class in my application. I have been reading Apple's Documentation and a book with a section on Core Data, however I am both struggling to get my head around it, and am yet to come across a section that describes the needs I mentioned above.

Any help with this (even just a link to a useful article) would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, have u created a managed object sub class for your entity?

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that, yes I have. Updated the question to include that.

Comment: In any core data tutorial, even in the simplest template from Apple, you will see that the entries in Core Data are accessed via fetchedResultsController instance. Simply make that instance accessible to any other class (a property of a Singleton perhaps) and you are done.

Comment: @PeterSarnowski correct me if I'm wrong, but judging from Apple's Documentation, isn't `fetchedResultsController` an iOS only class?

Comment: you are right, didn't notice that you need OS X not iOS, sorry. I haven't done much OSX coding, but from what I remember, the approach is similar - you should use a NSController subclass.